# Showing that $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ is not strictly convex

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Can somebody give an example that shows that $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ (regarding $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$) is not strictly convex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good start would be to give the definition of a strictly convex space.

Comment: So if $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ would be strictly convex, that would mean that for $f,g \in L^{\infty}, ||f||_{\infty} = ||g||_{\infty} = 1 : ||(f+g)/2||_{\infty} = 1 \Rightarrow f=g$. But I don't have an idea for useful functions to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\chi_{(a,b)} $be a characteristic function of an open interval $(a,b) .$ Take $f=\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)} , g =\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)} .$ Then $$||f||=||g|| =\frac{1}{2} ||f+g|| =1$$ but $$f\neq g.$$